# Greenplum - Out of memory

Tags: greenplum, hawq

When trying to query from gpdb cluster. getting Out of memory error with error code 53400.

**System Related information**

```
TOTAL RAM =30G
SWAP =15G
gp_vmem_protect_limit=8192MB
TOTAL segment = 8 Primary, 8 mirror = 16
SEGMENT HOST=2
```

**Getting error :**

```
ERROR: Out of memory (seg2 slice109 datanode01:40002 pid=21691)
SQL state: 53400
Detail: VM protect failed to allocate 8388608 bytes from system, VM Protect 4161 MB available
```

**We tried**

gpconfig -c gp_vmem_protect_limit -v 4114
vm.overcommit_ratio = 95

Then, getting this error.  P
ERROR: XX000: Canceling query because of high VMEM usage. Used: 3704MB, available 410MB, red zone: 3702MB

**Also , getting this symptom**

```
Prod=# show runaway_detector_activation_percent;
 runaway_detector_activation_percent 
-------------------------------------
 90
(1 row)
```

Please suggest what could be the setting in this case.
Also, What is the root cause of OOM error?

Any help on it would be much appreciated?

Comment: What is the query? How much RAM in the system? How many nodes, how many segments per segment server?

Comment: Please refer this link https://discuss.pivotal.io/hc/en-us/articles/205180467-How-to-Identify-Out-of-Memory-OOM-Errors

Comment: Thanks for support doc.  as per doc  OS  is reporting OOM  here 
   should i  set gp_vmem_protect_limit is set to low?  Currently getting following error  : ERROR: Out of memory (seg2 slice109 sungpmsh01:40002 pid=21691)
DETAIL: VM protect failed to allocate 8388608 bytes from system, VM Protect 4161 MB available

Comment: @ A. Scherbaum query - is with clause CTE expression. RAM - 30 GB Number of nodes - 2 data node - one primary node , one standby node  , Total Segment Host = 16 , segment host is 2

Comment: gpconfig -c gp_vmem_protect_limit -v 4114 vm.overcommit_ratio = 95, In this statemtn, gp_vmem_protect_limit should not be 4114. Calculate your server parameters from this link http://greenplum.org/calc/

Comment: @AnuraagVeerapaneni  Thanks for help, I have recalculated using the same calc site. gpconfig -c gp_vmem_protect_limit -v 2700  and implemented  but still it is showing the  Same error: OOM

Comment: Is there any change in values in the error message. Can you paste the error?

Comment: Now , error look likes  ERROR: 53400: Out of memory (seg3 slice181 datanode01:40003 pid=23454)

Comment: @AnuraagVeerapaneni   is it possible to discuss this over chat window?

Comment: Can you send detail message also?
Like Detail: VM protect failed to allocate 8388608 bytes from system, VM Protect 4161 MB available. is there a chat window in stackoverflow?

Comment: ERROR: 53400: Out of memory (seg3 slice181 datanode01:40003 pid=23454)  - This is complete error we are getting

Comment: Also, when I am using vmprotect limit 2700 with Overcommit ratio 95 . error got changed  and statment mem =1 GB  GETTING THIS ERROR ERROR: XX000: Canceling query because of high VMEM usage. Used: 2431MB, available 269MB, red zone: 2430MB (runaway_cleaner.c:135)  (seg2 slice42 datanode01:40002 pid=24032) (cdbdisp.c:1320)

Comment: Out of memory error is not coming now. but  getting  this error  ERROR: XX000: Canceling query because of high VMEM usage. Used: 2431MB, available 269MB, red zone: 2430MB (runaway_cleaner.c:135) (seg2 slice42 datanode01:40002 pid=24032) (cdbdisp.c:1320)

Comment: @AnuraagVeerapaneni  error changed  ERROR: XX000: Canceling query because of high VMEM

Comment: Can you post the query. We can try to optimize the query

Comment: Yes sure , Please join http://collabedit.com/7a5tf

Comment: @AnuraagVeerapaneni  OOM issue remains.